# GitLab Pipeline: Needs Job to execute only when previous job fail in multi-env. pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I need some help, with these:

I have these pipeline:
(4) Stages:

- Build
- Deploy
- Test
- Rollback

Each one of these stages have two jobs, each Env, means diferent VM, I need the Rollback stage  to be execute only when the respective previous fase (test) fails, ex:
The Job-4-RollB have to execute only when the Job-3-Test Fails, not any other.

I hope I explained well.

[Pipeline-Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEHGN.png)

Comment: can you please add some anonymized version of your .gitlab-ci.yml to the question, so we can get a better idea of what we are talking about exactly?

Answer (score 1):

use `when: on_failure` to do this. Unfortunately, this triggers when *any* job in the previous stage fails. So, you'll need some method to make the distinction which environment(s) to rollback in the final stage.

If you must have only these 4 pipelines stages, one way to make that determination would be to pass artifacts to the rollback job in order for the rollback job to know whether to perform the rollback. For example, an artifact containing either a `0` or `1`.

```yaml
.env-test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - make test $ENV_NAME > results.txt
  artifacts:
    paths: # could also consider `artifacts:reports:dotenv`
    - results.txt
    when: always

Env-1-Test:
  extends: .env-test
  variables:
    ENV_NAME: "1"

Env-2-Test:
  extends: .env-test
  variables:
    ENV_NAME: "2"


.rollback:
  when: on_failure # runs when 1 or more jobs from previous stage fail
  stage: rollback
  script: |
    test_result="$(cat results.txt)"
    if [[ "${test_results}" == "1" ]]; then
        make rollback 1
    else
        echo "no rollback needed for env 1"
    fi

Env-1-Rollback:
  extends: .rollback
  needs: [Env-1-Test]  # only get the Env-1-Test artifact, start right away

Env-2-Rollback:
  extends: .rollback
  needs: [Env-2-Test] # same, but for Env 2
```

One advantage of this approach is that `needs:` will allow the rollback job to run *immediately* after the corresponding test job fails.

This is probably the best way to handle this scenario.

You *can* orchestrate a pipeline to get the behavior that each rollback job will strictly only run when the corresponding env fails, but it will require a far more verbose job configuration. Basically *every* job would need to declare `needs:` AND every environment needs its own stages for build/test/deploy.

OR

You could make use of [parent-child pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/parent_child_pipelines.html) for each environment, such that each child pipeline's rollback stage corresponds to just 1 job/environment.

```yaml
Env-1-Child-Trigger:
  trigger:
    include: path/to/pipeline.yaml
  variables:
    ENV_NAME: "1"

Env-2-Child-Trigger:
  trigger:
    include: path/to/pipeline.yaml
  variables:
    ENV_NAME: "2"
```

Where your `pipeline.yaml` describes a singular build/deploy/test/rollback pipeline.

This is probably the most concise configuration.